# Deployment secription of Basic Authentication with JAX-WS for EJB 3.1

Tags: security, jax-ws, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, glassfish-3

There is good tutorial 
[Basic Authentication with  JAX-WS](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7627/bnccv?l=ru&a=view&q=Basic+Authentication+with+JAX-WS)

But it describe deployment description for web based application (war). Is it passable describe in ejb jar deployment description ?

For web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>SecurityConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>WRCollection</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>TutorialUser</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-constraint>BASIC</auth-constraint>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    </login-config>
        <security-role>
            <role-name>TutorialUser</role-name>
        </security-role>
```

I found out description of security rules by annotation -

[Security Annotations and Authorization in GlassFish and the Java EE 5 SDK](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/security_annotation/)

But is this is enough ?

Than you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotation and `sun-ejb.xml` is enough, but using Basic Authentication is not a good way.

Comment: maybe because it is not secure enough.. 
I desisted to use hands made authentication.